# How to convert rules token into variable for doing some calculation?

Tags: 7

I have a rule in which i have wrote a php code to **set the data** in node field.

```
 <?php echo "<br />" . t("Bid amount : "); ?>[flagged-comment:field-bid-amount]
```

**But i wants to do something like this :**
    **[flagged-comment:field-bid-amount] token**

```
 <?php echo "<br />" . t("Bid amount : "); ?>[flagged-comment:field-bid-amount] 
 <?php $a=[flagged-comment:field-bid-amount]; ?>
      <?php echo "<br />" . t("commision amount : ").$a/10; ?>
```

while doing the above its generating fatal error .

Comment: Why are you `echo`ing stuff? is **`Bid amount:`** `$xx.xx` suppose to show in some field?

Comment: yes i am setting the data in node field "details" using the rule

Comment: I want to show commision amount which should be divisible by 10 of bid amount

Comment: The answer from @NoSssweat seems to go in the right direction. But I wonder what the real purpose of the Rules Action in this question is. I suggest you edit your question to explain which Rules Event you're using (Drupal is initializing, before saving content, content is viewed, something else?), and which Rules conditions (if any).

Comment: i am using conditional rules ,on certain condition i have to set the data value in node field

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I just realised that this is more complex than originally thought since he wants to get a field value from a flagged comment and update the node field. Will have to get a component involved here. Feel free to answer this Q as I have to go to bed now.

Comment: exactly @No Sssweat

Comment: I *might* answer after I understand the question, right now I don't ... So first things first (to Drupal learner): please **edit** (repeat **edit**) your question to explain what you're trying to do (assume you're asking somebody who doesn't know what your code is doing, or is supposed to do). And finish it if you want with the current code you already included (with something like "this is what I tried so far"). Try to incorporate any relevant comments below your question (and then delete those comments since they became obsolete). PS to @NoSssweat: *slaap wel* ...

Comment: Simply i just want to knw is it possible to fetch available token [flagged-comment:field-bid-amount]  value into some variable this token shows me bid amount in my node field after saving token value in variable i can do division calculation for getting commission amount ( eg:flagged-comment:field-bid-amount]*10/100) that is 10% of bid amount but when i do so without storing a token value in some variable its generating fatal error.

Comment: @Drupallearner give me a bit, I am working on the answer.

Comment: @Drupallearner wow looks like there is no way to this with `calculate a data value` when I do `entity has field` field-bid-amount does not show up, nor in a comment component. It only shows up when your event is set to comment is viewed, saved, etc... but here you need when comment flag x is flagged.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens looks like there is no non-php answer for this, I think this scenario answers your Q of [When to use Flag's submodule flag_actions instead of Rules Actions?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/when-to-use-flags-submodule-flag-actions-instead-of-rules-actions)

Comment: @NoSssweat : sorry I don't believe you ... at least not yet ... Why do you think there is no non-php answer? I would also start from some Event like "comment is viewed, saved, etc", but then add a Rules Action to "Fetch an entity" (ie the node to which the comment is related). Apart from this, why do you think this also answers "my" other question you mentioned? PS to Drupal Learner: why don't you **edit** your question as I asked in my prior comment? FYI: I don't want to "guess" what your real question is (to not get blamed for guessing by mods ...)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens because he needs to use the event of `comment flag is flagged` and when you use this event any custom/created fields are not available in a Rule nor in a component. If you do `Entity has field` no custom/created comment fields show up.

Comment: @NoSssweat : hm, that helps a bit (things like *flagging the flags of flagging with flags* is fun ...). I need to think more about all this ...